# Can't understand the XSLT fragment

Tags: xslt

I have to comment a longer XSLT and there is a fragment, I don't understand:

```
<xsl:template name="description" match="node/richcontent[@TYPE='NOTE']">                              
    <xsl:element name="description"><xsl:value-of select="richcontent/html"/></xsl:element>      
</xsl:template>
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This matches any elements called `richcontent` with a parent of `node` with an attribute whose name is `TYPE` and value is `NOTE`, and for it, inserts a `description` element with the value of the `html` element within the `richcontent` element.

That is the input would be like:

```
<node>
    <richcontent type='OTHER'>...</richcontent>
    <richcontent type='NOTE'><richcontent><html>[Some content...]</html></richcontent></richcontent>
</node>
```

And the output would be like:

```
<description>[Some content...]</description>
```

Comment: The input would actually have `richcontent/richcontent`. The current context of the template is already `richcontent` and the `xsl:value-of` is looking for a child `richcontent`.

Comment: I'd also change "with an attribute whose value is `NOTE`" to "with an attribute that has the name `TYPE` and the value `NOTE`".

Comment: Is it right that way?

<node> 
<richcontent type='NOTE'> 
    <richcontent>
        <html>
           ...any conent...
        </html>
    </richcontent>
</richcontent>
</node>
Thank you!

Comment: @NadineSchöpper Daniel was correcting me, not you. The current answer is correct. TYPE='NOTE'

Comment: I#d rather say it's type='NOTE'

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect the code is wrong.

(a) It seems unlikely that an element called `richcontent` has a child element that is also called `richcontent`. Not impossible, but unlikely.

(b) The use of `<xsl:value-of>` means that the content of the `html` element is stripped of all its markup. That may be what's intended, but I would want to check.

Perhaps your brief only extends to discovering what the stylesheet does, and not to assessing whether it does what it's supposed to do. But usually any detailed review of old code like this will find lots of bugs, and I would hope that you are investigating possible bugs as you go.